# Python Selenium, send_keys letter by letter

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, time

How can I slower the `.send_keys()` ? So perhaps there can be a 0.25 second delay between every letter it send?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply write your own `send_keys()` method:

```
import time

def send_keys_delay(controller,keys,delay=0.25):
    for key in keys:
        controller.send_keys(key)
        time.sleep(delay)
```

and call `send_keys_delay(controller,keys)` instead of `controller.send_keys(keys)`. In case you want to set the delay (for instance to `0.5` seconds) you can also call: `send_keys_delay(controller,keys,0.5)`.

You can even make it more realistic by using *random* delays:

```
import random
import time

def send_keys_delay_random(controller,keys,min_delay=0.05,max_delay=0.25):
    for key in keys:
        controller.send_keys(key)
        time.sleep(random.uniform(min_delay,max_delay))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `time.sleep(0.25)` for an interval of 0.25 sec between every two letter it sends.

You can see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep).